# Automatically adding chapter title in section but not in toc

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Using KOMA's scrreprt, I am typing solutions to exercises in a book.

I have

```
\addchap{Page 42}
\addsec{Exercise 7}
\addsec{Exercise 8}
\addchap{Page 43}
\addsec{Exercise 9}
```

so that *Page 42* and *Exercise 7* appear without any numbers in the table of contents, which is what I want. (Note that these page numbers are not the page numbers of my LaTeX document but are page numbers of the book.)

However, since I often hand out solutions of individual exercises to students, I would like to have the page number mentioned together with the Exercise number on the same page.

Is there a way to have LaTeX automatically add the respective chapter name in front of the section name in the body of the document (but not in the TOC)? So that it looks like "Page 42 - Exercise 7" instead of just "Exercise 7".

If it is not possible directly inside the section name, perhaps there is a way to have the chapter (i.e. book page number) in the header.